# What's the difference between list-style-type and list-style?

Tags: html, css

When I am coming to the point of styling lists, I find myself unsure of the difference between `list-style` and `list-style-type`. Are they the same?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

From [www.w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style.asp) :

> "The list-style shorthand property sets all the list properties in one
>   declaration."

and [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-type.asp)

> "The list-style-type specifies the type of list-item marker in a
>   list."

`list-style` is the shorthand to set `list-style-type`, `list-style-position` and `list-style-image` properties all in one declaration.

Comment: Here is an alternative and much more canonical link to use instead of w3schools: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style

Answer (score 16):

No, they are not the same. The [`list-style`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#propdef-list-style) property is a shorthand property that always sets three properties: `list-style-type`, `list-style-position`, and `list-style-image`. For example

```
list-style: square;
```

is equivalent to setting all of the following:

```
list-style-type: square;
list-style-position: outside;
list-style-image: none;
```

Answer (score 11):

The list-style property is a shorthand that sets values for three different list related properties in one declaration:

```
ul {
  list-style: <list-style-type> <list-style-position> <list-style-image>;
}
```

**For example**

```
ul {
  list-style: circle outside none;
}
```

This is the same as longhand version:

```
ul {
  list-style-type: circle;
  list-style-position: outside;
  list-style-image: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

List-style is simply the shorthand version for styling your list. List style type specifically refers to the indicator to the left such as the ever popular none, or disc, decimal, etc.

So, you could say list-style: is to margin: as list-style-type: is to margin-right:

The options for list-style: are position, image and type.